# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numexpr.interpreter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, numexpr

there's something wrong with my installation of numexpr. When I run the following code

```
import numexpr as ne
```

I get the following error message:

> from numexpr.interpreter import MAX_THREADS, use_vml, **BLOCK_SIZE1**
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numexpr.interpreter'

Anybody has any idea what could be the cause?

I've installed and uninstalled numexpr multiple times already.
Some more info:
Python v 3.10.11
numexpr 2.8.4

Full error log:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\bemajco\Miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py",
> line 356, in compat_exec
> exec(code, globals, locals)
>
> File
> "c:\users\bemajco\myprojects\hyphen\learning\hyphen_learning.py", line
> 11, in 
> import numexpr as ne
>
> File
> "C:\Users\bemajco\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\numexpr_*init*_.py",
> line 24, in 
> from numexpr.interpreter import MAX_THREADS, use_vml, **BLOCK_SIZE1**
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numexpr.interpreter'

Comment: can you show us the whole snippet?

Comment: Added the whole error log in the original question, if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: no no the python script that your'e trying to execute...can you post the code here! or you're saying its failing on the first line of import itself?

Comment: it's failing on the import itself. That single line is the whole code.

Comment: when you do a `pip list`, does numexpr appear with the above version?

Comment: Yes, it does! numexpr 2.8.4

Comment: loooks like a known issue: https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/372 maybe try downgrading the version and see ?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same versions of Python and numexpre.  Moved a working project from Windows 10 to a fairly new WS2022.  The resolution for me was to install the MS Visual C++ runtime (VC_redist.x64.exe).